# Command line shell for identifying interfaces that are up and running

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any shell command for filtering interface names that are up and running

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `/sbin/ifconfig` and look for `UP`.

If you want just the names of the active interfaces, you need some scripting:

```
ifconfig | awk '/^[^ ]/ { name=$1; } /^ +UP / {print name;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check it with several commands:
See the content of the network interface file:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
```

Using `ip` command

```
ip a | grep -Eq ': eth0:.*state UP'
```

Or:

```
ifconfig | grep -Eq ': eth0:.*state UP'
```

Where `eth0` is your interface. Original [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121523/check-if-interface-eth0-is-up-configured)

Answer (score 0):

> ifconfig | awk -v RS="" '/MULTICAST/ && /UP/ && /RUNNING/ && /BROADCAST/ {print substr($1, 0, length($1)-1)}'